# How to visualise the division between the result of two aggregation in Kibana (metrics)

Tags: visualization, elasticsearch-aggregation, kibana-6

I'm using kibana 6.8.1-oss and I'd like to visualise the result of the division between two aggregation.

To be more specific, I have a field A and a field B. 
I want to create the result of sum(A)/sum(B) in a visualisation so I can put it into a dashboard.

Do you know if it's possible ?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a some research, I figured that this functionality is yet not supported by Kibana.